# Python script to query database with Where Clause Date using Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, where-clause, cx-oracle

**The Situation:**

I need to query an Oracle Database using a python script.
The query must select or filter a date column. So there is a where clause.

**The code**

```
startdate = '2018-01-01'
sql = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE >= ?"
cursor_oracle = connection_oracle.cursor()
df_ora = pd.read_sql(sql, connection_oracle, params=startdate)
```

**The Problem:**

I've been hacking at this all day, and I get so many different errors:

- Date parameter, but expecting int,
- SQL Execution bad termination..

How do I simply query a database table with a where clause where the column is a date field and I need to specify a date value?

Do I need to convert my date value to a date object?
So - what I mean by that is:

```
date_to_be_queried = "2020-01-01"
date_to_be_queried_object = datetime.someConversionFunction(date_to_be_queried).
```

I've reached my wits-end.

**The error message:**

the current error message (the new kid on the block) is:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE >= ?': ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

clues:

the field type of the MY_DATE column is DATE
an example of a typical entry in this column is:

2002-03-28 00:00:00

Comment: `Date parameter, but expecting int` Is the date column encoded as an integer? E.g. one format I have seen is that the date is represented as an integer like `20220523`. Not best practice, but it does happen. Can you provide the type of the database column called my_date?

Comment: Your format string in `strptime()` doesn't match the date string. The date string contains `-` but the format string has `/`.

Comment: apologies .. I changed my code so it is clearer.

Comment: `SQL = f"""SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE >= '{startdate}'"""` should work

Comment: OK @ALollz.. let's give it a shot

Comment: no I get another error with this method @ALollz. ORA-01861: Literal mismatch with format string

Comment: f"SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE MY_DATE >= DATE {startdate}" Might work https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ

Comment: I found the answer guys.. I'll post it when I have time.